# Finding the root of $x^3+3x^2+4$ knowing the roots of $x^3+3x^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I get the root of $f(x) = x^3+3x^2+4$ using the fact that $-3$ is a root of $h(x) = x^3+3x^2$ (also knowing that $h$ is a vertical translation of $4$ units of $f$)?
Does not seems to be hard, but I'm stuck. Already tried using the derivative but could not achieve the result.

Comment: Welcome; Did you draw both graphs?

Comment: notice that if this was possible in general, we would be able to iterate the process and find roots of any polynomial by only knowing the root of $p(x)=x$.

Comment: In general, you can't really transform the roots of $p(x)$ to get roots of $p(x)+a$. This is in contrast to *horizontal* shitfs: it is a trivial matter to transform the roots of $p(x)$ to get the roots of $p(x+a)$.

Answer (score 6):

There is no easy way to get from the fact that $x^3+ 3x^2$ has a root at $x=-3$ to finding roots of $x^3 + 3x^2 + 4$

There is a root and it is at  $x = -(\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{8}} + \sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{8}} + 1)$

But you would not be expected to find it unless you know the cubic formula.

Comment: At the beginning of your post :$x^3+3x^2$

Comment: I wouldn't say the last sentence is completely correct - in this case one can easily guess a root then divide to find a quadratic equation

Comment: @kevinkayaks Except, there isn't an easy root to find here.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I was simply incorrect - I thought I spotted $x=1$ but must have autocompleted to $x^3 + 3 x^2 -4$ in my brain when I decided that ; )

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the roots to $x^3+3x^2$ offers no help in this case since the equation $x^3+3x^2+4$ has no rational roots at all. The only roots it does have can be found using the cubic formula or even just Cardano's method, but that is about it. It cannot really be solved via factorization.